# How can we set a text field in android that only allow us to enter positive integer number

Tags: android

How can i set a text field in ANDROID that only allow positive integer numbers like 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on

Answer (score 2):

Put this line in the xml:

```
    android:inputType="numberSigned"
```